# C++ using pointers, nothing is passed

Tags: c++, pointers

Code executes, but nothing gets passed on image_data (line 44 the write_function)

So I have no working array for the function (line 11), why is that so? I thought passing on the reference for image_data should be enough? (I'm used to it, mostly developing JAVA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Expects bgra image data
//Only makes bgr and bgra with 8 bits per pixel pictures
//Expects big endian ushorts
//makes no checks on the data supplied!
void write_tga(ofstream& output,char image_data[],unsigned short xWidth,unsigned short yWidth,bool transparency) //Line 11 - Line 11 - Line 11 - Line 11
{
    char zero = static_cast<char>(0x00);
    char two = static_cast<char>(0x02);

    //Convert uint to char Array
    unsigned char xWidth_arr[2];
    unsigned char yWidth_arr[2];
    memcpy(xWidth_arr, &xWidth, 2);
    memcpy(yWidth_arr, &yWidth, 2);

    char header[18] = {zero,zero,two,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero, zero,zero,zero,zero, xWidth_arr[0],xWidth_arr[1],yWidth_arr[0],yWidth_arr[1],static_cast<char>(0x18),zero};
    //enabling transparency
    if(transparency){
        header[16]= static_cast<char>(0x20);
        header[17]= static_cast<char>(0x08);
    }
    char footer[26] = {zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero,zero, 'T','R','U','E','V','I','S','I','O','N','-','X','F','I','L','E','.',zero};

    output.write((char*)&header,sizeof(header));
    output.write((char*)&image_data,sizeof(image_data));
    output.write((char*)&footer,sizeof(footer));
    output.close();
    cout << image_data[0] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream output("data.tga",ios::binary);
    output.seekp(0);

    char zero = static_cast<char>(0x00);
    char image_data[12] = {static_cast<char>(0xff),static_cast<char>(0xff),static_cast<char>(0xff), zero,zero,zero, zero,zero,zero, zero,zero,zero};

    write_tga(output,image_data,2,2,false); //Line 44 - Line 44 - Line 44 - Line 44
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sizeof (imagedata) is not what you expect, insert some debug code to see what it is. (and change your cout to `cout << image_data << endl;` to get 'some' output - though nothing useful)

Comment: Instread of `output.write((char*)&image_data,sizeof(image_data));`, say `output.write(image_data, n);`, and you have to pass the size `n` somehow, because the array size doesn't survive the decay-to-pointer of `image_data`. (It might be that in your case you can just say `12`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do in this code:

```
output.write((char*)&image_data,sizeof(image_data));
```

Array name is a pointer. You're writing to `output` its content (the memory address), not the actual data it points to. Remove the `&` operator to write the content it points to, which is what you wanted, I think. Or use `&` on the first member (e.g.: `(char*)&image_data[0]`).

`sizeof` returns a size of a pointer for `image_data`. Use a "size" parameter to convey the size.

And you're abusing `static_cast` for no apparent reason.

Comment: I think that taking the `operator&` of an array gives the address of the first element of the array; not sure if that's still true when the array is a function parameter, but that's the way I'd bet.

Comment: array as a function parameter is a pointer, taking its address gives you its address, not the address it points to.

Comment: Got it working: output.write(image_data,n); n is the size parameter that has to be passed on to the function. Why do I abuse static_cast? Is there an easier way? (actually got that from an example from some other site)

Comment: @whyRegister, you're abusing `static_cast` because it's totally unnecessary. Any integer constant that fits will convert to `char` without casting.

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not have dynamic arrays. There's an unfortunate syntax choice that `char imagedata[]` may be used as a parameter, but it's actually treated as a `char * imagedata`. This means that the sizeof operator is returning the size of a pointer, not the size of the array.

Comment: `imagedata` isn't a dynamic array, and it could be passed as an array (by reference), but the code shown doesn't do that.

Comment: @Ben, of course `imagedata` isn't a dynamic array, because C++ doesn't have such a thing! (`vector` doesn't quite count). It could be passed as an array either by reference or not, but the size would need to be a constant specified in the parameter list. I'm sure you already know that, but I gotta keep the record straight.

Comment: Whaddaya mean C++ doesn't have a dynamic array?  What do you call `new int[n]`?  And if you did pass a statically-sized array by reference, the compiler could find the size during template parameter inference.