# C++ any hex to char

Tags: c++, hex

Is there a better way from hex to char?

```
char one = static_cast<char>(0x01);
```

(asking because of this --> [C++ using pointers, nothing is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823216/c-using-pointers-nothing-is-passed) )

Also is there a fast way to make a char array out of hex values (eg. 0x12345678 to a char array)?

Comment: "Better" as in "something that actually works"?

Comment: This works as far as I can tell (look at the link I provided)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

```
std::string hexify(unsigned int n)
{
  std::string res;

  do
  {
    res += "0123456789ABCDEF"[n % 16];
    n >>= 4;
  } while(n);

  return std::string(res.rbegin(), res.rend());
}
```

Credits to [STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-5-of-n) for the "index into char array" trick.

Also beware when printing `char`s, which are signed on some platforms. If you want `128` to print as `80` rather than `FFFFFFFF`, you have to prevent it from being treated as `-1` by converting to unsigned char first: `hexify((unsigned char)(c));`

Comment: And about the first one? For just a single character?

Comment: Sure: `char c; std::string result = hexify(c);`.

Comment: What if `n` is 0? You probably don't want an empty string in that case. Perhaps a `do { } while(n)` would be a better choice.

Comment: `n >> 4` doesn't actually do anything ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What do you intend to be stored in the variable `one`?

The code as written will store the ASCII character `0x01` into `one`. This is a control character, not a printable character. If you're looking for the *digit* 1, then you need to say so explicitly:

```
char one = '1';
```

That stores the actual character, not the ASCII code `0x01`.

If you are trying to convert a number into the string representation of that number, then you need to use [one of these mechanisms](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm). If instead, you are trying to treat a 32-bit integer as a sequence of 4 bytes, each of which is an ASCII character, that is a different matter. For that, you could do this:

```
uint32_t someNumber = 0x12345678;
std::string myString(4, ' ');
myString[0] = static_cast<char>((someNumber >> 24) & 0xFF);
myString[1] = static_cast<char>((someNumber >> 16) & 0xFF);
myString[2] = static_cast<char>((someNumber >> 8) & 0xFF);
myString[3] = static_cast<char>((someNumber) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: I know what I want, you should look at the link I provided

Comment: @whyRegister: it's reasonable to provide a link to explain how you got interested in some question, but you should still make this question independently meaningful. SO questions aren't meant requires a treasure chase before answering.  As is, it's a terribly worded ambiguous mess.

Comment: @Nicol: +1, but `std::string` doesn't have a constructor from a lone length value... you'll need e.g. `myString(4, ' ')`. Anyway, `std::ostringstream` and `std::hex` should probably be seen as the best approach for beginners....